# Creating a Android 13 (API 33) app with forcehybrid

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android

As of November 1, 2023 all updates to apps on the Android Play Store need to be targeted at API 33 (Android 13).

The [documentation for the Hybrid Mobile SDK 11.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/migrate_all_apps_from_10.2_to_11.0.htm) say that the Target API is 33 and that it uses Cordova Command Line 12, which is also target API 33. However, when I run the `forcehybrid create ...` script the terminal says:

```
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms/android
        Package: <com.package.name>
        Name: <AppName>
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android Target SDK: android-32
        Android Compile SDK: 32
```

How do I get it to make a project for API 33, or at least get the project to upgrade to API 33 so we can release updates on the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to create a build for 32 despite what the documentation said but I was able to then just upgrade it to 33 following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50404548/how-to-change-my-apps-target-api-level-from-23-to-26).